# How to print select option on console while submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a `form` which has some `input` and `select` elements and a submit button. When the form is submitted I want to know which drop-down option is chosen.

I have achieved that by using the change jQuery method, but I want to achieve this on form submit because I have to make two AJAX calls; one to `POST` the value and one to `GET` the value. By doing it with `change` it is making an AJAX call on change and one after clicking on submit button. I want to achieve that by submitting the form only.

Also, I cannot use the `value` attribute on my `<option>` tags as the dropdown list is created in the backend

```html
<form id="formId" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()" />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()" />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">
      <option>--------------------------------------</option>
      <option>ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="tbl"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myselect").on("change", function() {
    currentlyClickedOutlet = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "DateWiseOlWiseSales",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        Outlet: currentlyClickedOutlet,
      },
    });
  });

  $("#formId").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "DateWiseOlWiseSales",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: {
        fromdate: $("#startdate").val(),
        todate: $("#enddate").val(),
        outlet: $("#all").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log("test",tableValue);
        $("#formId").hide();
        let formatedData = formatData(data);
        renderTable(formatedData);
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $("#export").show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your `<option>` tags the `value` attribute and set that to be what you want to be logged when you click submit.

You can then use the `.submit()` method on your form to listen for a submit event, and use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from taking default action and submitting. Then you can get the selected dropdown item by using:

```
$("#myselect").val();
```

You can then log out this value to see it in the console.

See example below:

```js
$("#formId").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting
  const dp_value = $("#myselect").val();
  console.log(dp_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="formId" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">
      <option value="none">--------------------------------------</option>
      <option value="all">ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, if you are planning to `POST` all your data using *ajax* I recomend you use `.serializeArray()` to convert all your form inputs into an array. Then using this array, you can use `.reduce` to convert it into an object identical to the one you would recieve via a submit POST method:

```js
$("#formId").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting
  const data = $(this).serializeArray();
  const post_data = data.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => ({...acc, [name]: value}), {});
  console.log(post_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="formId" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">
      <option value="none">--------------------------------------</option>
      <option value="all">ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you cannot use `value` property, I suggest you use `.find(':selected')` to get the select `option`, and then use `.textContent` to get the text in the `option`:

```js
$("#formId").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting
  const dp_value = $("#myselect").find(":selected").get(0).textContent;
  console.log(dp_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="formId" method="get">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>End Date:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">
      <option>--------------------------------------</option>
      <option>ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to do this without `value` because from backend i am only getting list of outlets not values   my json is like `["jayanagar","malleshwaram","kolar"]`

Comment: and you are using this list to create the dropdown?

Comment: yupp ..is there any other way

Comment: hm, there should be, but if you are using this list to create the dropdown can't you use add the `value` attribute to it when create the `<option>`

Comment: why are you using const

Comment: @manishthakur just because I don't need to modify the values later, if you can use `const`, then if can't use `const` use `let` then if you can't use `let` use `var`. In this case you don't need to use `const`, you can use `var` or `let`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line of code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
```

Or if you prefer using jQuery:

```
console.log($("#mySelect").val());
```

It will log the value of your select element (the selected option) to the console.

Comment: Or jQuery-way: `// console.log("test",  $("#myselect").val());`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing the selected option value in the form submit.
Try this :

```
$("#formId").submit(function(event) {
var value = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
     ..... // your code goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected option using the below code snippet.

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
})
```

else you can do it like `$('select').val();` , But make sure your options has values.

EDITED:

If you you have the array of values `var arr = ["option1","option2","option3"]` Then you can append the options to the `select`

```
for(let i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
$('select').append('<option value="'+arr[i]+'"></option>');
}
```

Here you are assigning the data within the array as values of the options as well. Try this.

Comment: $(select).val(); will get the data which is assigned to the 'value' attribute of the options, not the text with in the option tag. so please give the 'value' to each options and try.

Comment: the edited part is to fill the drop-down i have already achieved that